# Is there an option for "Mark All Emails as Read Across All Folders" in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, context-menu

I have lots of Outlook folders (30+) and they each get a trickle of over 200 emails a day.

Usually I scan through each folder to make sure nothing important is in there and right click on the folder and press `E` to 'Mark All as Read'.

This gets tedious and I want to eliminate the second step so I can just scan through my folders then press a button to mark all subfolders and folders as read at the end.

I would like to say this differs from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/161349/outlook-2007-is-there-a-way-to-mark-all-messages-in-all-subfolders-as-read) as I would like to know which emails are new and not have them automatically all be marked as read when they come in.

Comment: 30×200 emails a day is a trickle?!  But seriously, if the below answers don’t work for you, it might be possible to do something with VBA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Search Folder tip does the work. To do this go "Folder" tab > press "New Search Folder" > on the pop window select "Unread mail" > Press OK.
This will create a folder, like all your others, on the left menu (where you have Inbox, Sent Items so on), named Search Folder > Unread Mail and you can right click and "Mark all as read".

Comment: This is much better than the other answer as it doesn't involve having to 'search' manually and wait for the search to complete, it will always now be there and show me my unread mail.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a single button that does this, not in the Outlook client.

You could use a search query and then select all (Ctrl - A), right-click, and then mark all as read.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:
Based on the other answer of doing a search, I created a new customized search folder and selected all of my folders that I wanted to do a mass "Mark as Read" action, with a criteria of "unread".  This made a new "Unread" search folder for just the targeted folders.  Now I can do a single right-click and "Mark All as Read".

Comment: Could you please detail step-by-step how to make a 'search folder'? This incorporates the other answer and expands upon it so I'll probably mark your answer as correct if you do.

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps;
click on search box
type: isread:no
next to the search box is an option which you specify the search scope (current folder, All mailboxes,...) choose the one you need
once the search is done, press Ctrl+A, right click "mouse", and press read
ta-da. it's done :)

Comment: Please, format properly your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution. I map the macro to a button in the header. Would be nice to add a right-click item but I haven't figured that out yet:

```
' Top level Sub that should be linked to a button or context menu
Public Sub MarkAllRead()
    Call ProcessUnreadFolder(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder)
End Sub

Public Function ProcessUnreadFolder(oFolder As Outlook.Folder)
   
    For i = 1 To oFolder.Folders.Count
        ProcessUnreadFolder (oFolder.Folders(i))
    Next
    
    If oFolder.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To oFolder.Items.Count
            MarkItemRead (oFolder.Items(i))
        Next
    End If

End Function

Public Function MarkItemRead(oItem As Object)
    If oItem.UnRead = True Then
        oItem.UnRead = False
    End If
End Function
```